# Conditional formatting if date is before today AND adjacent cell is empty

Tags: excel, date, if-statement, conditional-formatting

Let's say I have dates in cell G1:G999 and H1:H99. I am trying to establish conditional formatting for column G to highlight the cells with dates that are prior to today AND the adjacent cell in row H is empty.
I was wondering if this can be done in this sort of combination.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula:

```
=AND($G1<TODAY(),$H1="")
```

and apply to range (adjust as necessary to your last row)

```
=$G$1:$G$999
```

[image]